# laravel atymic/twitter is not running on linux server but working on macbook (homebrew)

Tags: laravel

I am facing a strange issue with [Atymic Twitter](https://github.com/atymic/twitter)

I have same version of php i.e. 7.4.22 on my local (macbook) and live server (ubuntu)

This is package running awesome on local but shows below error on server (ubuntu)

Details:

php 7.4.22

laravel :7.30.4

atymic/twitter 3.1.13

[image]

Comment: did you check that the webserver process(fpm) also uses php version 7.4 and not only the CLI?

Comment: server does not have such service in /etc/init.d/ directory

Comment: do you use nginx or apache?

Comment: I am using apache

Comment: Could you add a `phpinfo();` and a `die()` in your index.php to check the installed extensions?

Comment: oh, its using 7.2. 
I had already changed php version but its still 7.2 . How I can change this version to 7.4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apache process may still be using an other version of PHP. You can change that version using the following commands:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.2
sudo a2enmod php7.4
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I disabled all other versions but forgot to try 7.2.
After disabling 7.2 , It was actually changed to 7.4.
Thanks a lot.